# S3 policy for allowing requests with Cognito credentials: AWS

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to policy json into my S3 bucket which will make my bucket accessible using Cognito credentials. Following is the policy:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "Federated": "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketName12345",
        "Condition": {
            "StringLike": {
                "s3:prefix": "cognito/angularApplicationName/"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "Federated": "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:DeleteObject"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucketName12345/cognito/angularApplicationName/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}",
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucketName12345/cognito/angularApplicationName/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/*"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

but I get a warning saying "your bucket is public....". Since I'm very new to AWS, can somebody point out what am I missing here?

Comment: This policy seems like it might grant access to your bucket to *all* cognito apps, not just yours.  I suspect that these statements belong not in a bucket policy, but rather in an IAM policy that is associated with a role that cognito is allowed to assume.  Did you find this as an example?  And, if so, can you provide a link to it?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, this is where I got the reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_s3_cognito-bucket.html
Is it IAM policy? Should create an IAM user with this policy and then add that IAM user in my S3 policy?

Comment: Yes, that's an IAM policy, but you don't create an IAM *user* -- you want an IAM *role*... and you don't need anything in the bucket policy.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, once I have IAM role and policy for that role in place, how do I link that role with S3 and Cognito?

Comment: See [Role-Based Access Control](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/role-based-access-control.html).  Now I understand why you tried `"Principal": {
            "Federated": "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com"
        },` in your bucket policy.  Where you see this is a *trust policy*  (separate from the role policy) that grants permission to the service that will be accessing that role.